# Can't export HTML table to Excel when using attributes on the table elements

Tags: jquery, html, excel, html-table

I'm trying to export an HTML table to Excel using this easy function that I found on the internet:

```
$("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#tabla_datos').html());
    e.preventDefault();
});​
```

It works pretty well, but when I add an attribute to any elements in my table, like rowspan or colspan, the Excel does not export correctly.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="tabla_datos">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Columna 1</th>
        <th>Columna 2</th>
        <th>Columna 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'>Dato 1</td>
        <td>Dato2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>Dato 3</td>
        <td>dato 4</td>
        <td>Dato5</td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>

<input type="button" id="btnExport" value=" Export Table data into Excel " />​
```

And here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WAR2v/

Comment: I am facing same problem aslo while opening file it generates error that file might have different format than specified i.e "xsl" and no grid lines of this generated excel also disappears.......

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but did you try to encode your URI?

This code works for me:

```
$("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('#tabla_datos').html()));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```